# What's the meaning of "roll out" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The following is an advice given to someone who is looking for ways to make a couple thousand bucks in a short period:

> With no deets on your situation it's really hard to help you. But I will say for sh-ts and giggles my fiance and I went garage saleing like a mofo last summer for shit to re-sell on Craigslist. Made quite a bit of cash. But selling ANYTHING on Craigslist is a fucking bit-h.
>
> But on the other hand if you're hard up for money. You can **roll out** with $50 and easily turn it into $200+ if you have the time and patience,
>
> I found an expensive light fixture for $35 that I sold for $125, and a set of 2011 F150 side view mirrors I got for $100, and sold for $350.

I have a general idea of what he meant by the term *roll out*, but what exactly does it mean? I found a few definitions of the phrase *roll out* in the dictionaries, but they don't seem to fit the context. The definition I found are:

> 1. to get out of bed.
> 2. *football* to execute a rollout.
> 3. to show (a new type of aircraft) to the public for the first time
> 4. to launch (a new film, product, etc) in a series of stages over an area, each stage involving an increased number of outlets
> 5. to cause (pastry) to become flatter and thinner by pressure with a rolling pin

Comment: Have you searched *at all*? "the official launch or introduction of a new product or service: *campaigns these days look a lot like product roll-outs; a national roll-out of digital satellite systems*" (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/roll--out) -- this phrase is widely used these days to mean "start", "set off", "get going" ...

Comment: @Kris It honestly did not occur to me that definition #4 was what the term meant in the context. "to officially launch or introduce a new product or service" sounds so serious to me like some multi-million dollar corporation product launch. The guy was simply trying to resale second-hand items on Craigslist. Anyway, the term is unknown to me and I just wanted a confirmation of its meaning.

Comment: This requires a bit of mental imagery to differentiate between activity that is similar to a "product roll-out" and a more literal "roll-out of your garage or driveway on a Saturday morning to begin your treasure hunting at the garage sales". Most people who depend on making a living that way are not likely to have any concern about product roll-outs and how those product roll-outs affect their lives. I doubt they would describe it in those terms or with that in mind. The literal "roll-out" becomes the metaphor for the start of the activity - find the treasure, buy it, sell it for a profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is like the phrase "Let's roll." which has been used extensively as a term to move and start an activity, attack, mission or project. To "roll out" means just that - to start an activity.

"You can roll out with $50..." means "You can start with $50..."

More on "Let's roll" can be found by Google search, as in [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_roll).

Comment: Try to encourage to the OP to do some prior research. This question is GR.

Comment: @Kris I absolutely had no idea that the term *roll out* had a connection with the term *let's roll*. The term *let's roll* is readily available in the dictionaries, but the term *roll out* with the definition of *to start an activity* can not be found.